# Regular expression to find pattern in string in PHP

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-match

Suppose I have a string that looks like:

`"lets refer to [[merp] [that entry called merp]] and maybe also to that entry called [[blue] [blue]]"`

The idea here is to replace a block of `[[name][some text]]` with `<a href="name.html">some text</a>`.

So I'm trying to use regular expressions to find blocks that look like `[[name][some text]]`, but I'm having tremendous difficulty.

Here's what I thought should work (in PHP):
`preg_match_all('/\[\[.*\]\[.*\]/', $my_big_string, $matches)`

But this just returns a single match, the string from `'[[merp'` to `'blue]]'`.  How can I get it to return the two matches `[[merp][that entry called merp]]` and `[[blue][blue]]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Quantifiers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) like the `*` are by default [*greedy*](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-greed.html),

which means, that as much as possible is matched to meet conditions. E.g. in your sample a regex like `\[.*\]` would match everything from the first `[` to the last `]` in the string. To change the default behaviour and make quantifiers *lazy* (*ungreedy, reluctant*):

- Use the `U (PCRE_UNGREEDY)` [modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) to make all quantifiers lazy
- Put a `?` after a specific quantifier. E.g. `.*?` as few of any characters as possible

---

1.) Using the U-[modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) a pattern could look like:

```
/\[\[(.*)]\s*\[(.*)]]/Us
```

Additional used the s (PCRE_DOTALL) [modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) to make the `.` dot also match newlines. And added some `\s` whitespaces in between `][` which are in your sample string. `\s` is a [shorthand](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) for `[ \t\r\n\f]`.

There are two capturing groups `(.*)` to be replaced then. [Test on regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/jX9yQ0)

---

2.) Instead using the `?` to making each quantifier lazy:

```
/\[\[(.*?)]\s*\[(.*?)]]/s
```

[Test on regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/uB3wR8)

---

3.) Alternative without modifiers, if no square brackets are expected to be inside `[...]`.

```
/\[\[([^]]*)]\s*\[([^]]*)]]/
```

Using a `^` negated [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) to allow `[^]]*` any amount of characters, that are NOT `]` in between `[` and `]`.  This wouldn't require to rely on greediness. Also no `.` is used, so no s-modifier is needed.

[Test on regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/bR5jT1)

---

Replacement for all 3 examples according to your sample: `<a href="\1">\2</a>` where `\1` correspond matches of the first [parenthesized group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html),...

Answer (score 4):

The regex you're looking for is `\[\[(.+?)\]\s\[(.+?)\]\]` and replace it with `<a href="$1">$2</a>`

The regex pattern matched inside the `()` braces are captured and can be back-referenced using $1, $2,...

Example on [regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/oZ5hC6)

Comment: `\s*` would be more robust